# Are there languages more suitable for loud or crowded situations than others?

Tags: phonetics

I'm an Italian native speaker but I speak English everyday for work.

When I'm with English native speakers I often hear them asking to repeat words, especially if there's a lot of noise around.

I realized this kind of situation happens very rarely when I speak with other iltalians. We usually never misunderstand a word, at worst we ask to repeat the whole sentence because we got distracted.

Something I think "backs" my hypothesis is the fact the English language makes heavy use of the "spelling" to help the other understand specific words, names, etc... While in other languages such as Italian, Spanish, Portuguese, and probably most of the Latin derived languages, this isn't common at all.

So the question is, are there any evidences that some languages are more suitable to talk in loud environments than others?